# Block screen lock to run if an app is running a specific task

Tags: macos, script, lock-screen

My system is set up to lock the screen after 5 minutes. The screensaver starts just a few seconds before and then it locks. The problem I'm running is that if Final Cut Pro X is playing a Project (timeline) it won't block the screen lock process, so, my question is if there's a way to do it.
If I'm watching a movie on Iina, which I believe has the same behaviour on other media players, this doesn't happen.

Any suggestions?

TIA

Comment: It's the app that can hold the screensaver display timer, not the OS. VLC does it in play, you can watch all day without the screensaver kicking in, but if you pause, then it will kick in as normal after x minutes. It's not clear from your question whether you're trying to lock the screen or prevent it locking.

Comment: Yes, it is not so clear. I assumed you wanted to lock the screen and I would just do it with keyboard shortcut - like "Super" + "L"

Comment: After 5 minutes of mouse and keyboard inactivity the screen saver starts. 1 minute after the screen gets locked, asking for the password. You can set it up this way in System Preferences > Security & Privacy. What I want has been answered, and in fact answered my question. I’ll send feedback to Apple. Thank you all!